# How to open visual studio without administrator rights

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When i open visual studio  2010 it is automatically running with administrator.

Let me know how can i open visual studio  without administrator rights.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This solution should only be used if [Flabetvibes solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22063402/1951524) does not work.

1. Navigate to the Visual Studio install folder (commonly `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\`)
2. Right-click **devenv.exe** > **Properties**
3. Go to the **Security** tab and click **Advanced** button.
4. Click on **Change** right beside the owner (the current owner may be "Administrators").
5. Enter your Windows user name into the text area and click **Check Names**.
6. If found, click **OK** and **Apply** etc.

Visual Studio should now start in normal mode (without "Administrator").

This has to be repeated every time a new update is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you are running Visual Studio 2010 under a Windows system, then the solution might be:

1. Right click on the Visual Studio icon
2. Choose *Properties*
3. Select the *Compatibility* tab
4. Unchecked *Run this program as an administrator* inside the *Privilege Level* group box

Hope this idea is useful.

Comment: when i see this in Compatibility tab. Run this program as an administrator -checkbox is unchecked only...

Comment: Sounds like you are not the administrator of the system, isn't it ?

Comment: Okay, to apply the privilege level to all users on the computer and regardless of which shortcut is used to start the application, click *Change setting for all users* under the *Compatibility tab* and see if the other *Run this program as an administrator* is unchecked too...